# How to stop the scrolling of the fullcalendar on the mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

Need to stop the scrolling on the mobile device when using the full calendar and when i set the height and content height as auto then this will set different height for dates on the desktop view. Help me to change the height as auto for the mobile device

Added height and content height

```
$('#event-calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'Next',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    height:'auto',//contentHeight:'auto',

});
```

Comment: fullCalendar is not really optimised for mobile use unfortunately. Most of the views (with the possible exception of day-only views) will not scale well on mobile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843788/665961
has the working answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure much, but this I used in Daily calendar, try to set minTime and MaxTime. Setting this will restrict the remaining times.